# javascript: completely remove top.location.hash?

Tags: javascript, hash

If I have already a hash in my addressbar like e.g. domain.com#whatever and I call:

`top.location.hash = "";`

the #wathever is transformed into domain.com# without anything.

Is it possible to completely remove the hash? So there is no `#` left.

Because if I call `top.location.hash = "";` the page jumps to it's top, because a # is passed to the url. I want to prevent that.

Comment: without reloading the page? I'd say no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
top.location = ''
```

should do that, but it will cause a page reload.  I don't think there's any way to remove it programmatically.

Comment: ok, is it possible then to just set it "#" but don't make the page jump to it's top? I wouldn't mind if there is a # left in the url. I just don't want my site to jumpt to the top.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295845/remove-hash-without-page-jump should answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

it's possible with history.pushState, e.g.:

```
history.pushState({}, '', './');
```

Of course it's IE<10 incompatible, but works for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location = window.location.href.replace( /#.*/, "");
```

Comment: This will do the trick but I don't think OP wants the page to reload.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to reliably do so without causing the page to refresh, in which case you could use the location.href property.