# javascript top.location.hash = ""; without browser jumping to top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, hash

```
top.location.hash = "";
```

adds a # to my addressbar. As soon as `top.location.hash = "";` is called and a # is added my browser window jumps to its top.

Is there any chance a could prevent that?

```
$('#element').live('click', function() {
        top.location.hash = "map";
    });
```

Comment: In this case it may help to know what you're trying to accomplish with the **top.location.hash = '';**

Comment: Nothing actually. I just have a #hashLikeThis already in my address. When I click a specific element on my page i change the #hash to nothing so there is no confusion for the user. updated my post!

Comment: Do you care if the browser reloads the page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript: completely remove top.location.hash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383591/javascript-completely-remove-top-location-hash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the hash to something that is not significant and never used, e.g. an underscore. AFAIK, changing the hash to nothing will always scroll the page to the top.

Comment: True, but he wants the hash to disappear. Only possible way to set top.location which will reload the page