# Strange #_=_ appear at the end of url after response.redirect ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, response.redirect

Anyone here using `Response.Redirect()` method, do have you encountered some strange characters attached to the end of the uri on the browser address bar?
The strange characters are **hash, underscore, equal sign and underscore** (without spaces) such as below... I have no idea what are these all about and when these strange characters appear, the redirection didn't happen properly.

```
 #_=_
```

Any insights on this please share. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some code? Also, what browser(s) are you seeing this on?

Comment: By chance are you using facebook login on your site?

Comment: yes, i'm using custom facebook login on my site, somehow it happened

Answer (score 1):

Anything in the `location-part` of a URL that follows a `#` refers to an anchor in the page, usually an `<a name="">` or `<whatever id="">`. Some web sites use them (probably with client-side Javascript) to perform magic, but since you are asking this, I get the feeling that's not the case for you. So, there's no real rhyme or reason to that the existence or absence of those characters in and of themselves would cause the redirection to work or not. In fact, they aren't even sent to the server in the HTTP request (at least, Firefox doesn't).

Have you had a look at the HTTP request exchanges when this is happening? Something like Live HTTP Headers, HttpFox or Firebug (look at the Net panel) will help you with this, and might point you to where the errant `#_=_` is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution based on a couple others out there:

```
$(function () {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("#_=_") > -1) {
        //remove facebook oAuth response bogus hash
        if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
            history.pushState('', document.title, window.location.pathname);
        } else {
            window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(location.hash, "");
        }
    }
});
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7845639/1467810

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15323220/1467810

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2295951/1467810