# Facebook Authentication and strange redirect behaviour

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, redirect, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm currently testing an OAuth implementation of facebook connect using http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com.

I've got a FacebookController with 2 simple actions called **LogOn** and **CallBack**.

Everything works fine and the user is logged correctly into my system.

The problem is when the CallBack action is called, something strange happens that makes a simple

```
return Redirect(loggedUrl);
```

redirecting to the correct logged url but ending with the following characters: `#_=_`

It appears that the Facebook server sends the information to my webserver using the following HTTP header:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Location: http://mywebsite.com/Facebook/CallBack/?state=1&code=AQCXexr10uxANSBOu9JqrBDxqPkWbsyxM1S9ltuY9XwCXW7eGsOII329SthClxOSM_a7wJvwrXh1_O3D5I7E_nxCDTWDLpyYdMpMUfw4zMWcQ4oV2PmRkIMd2NfPYRKlkLgkurEzka1CjAF1jp8Xb3crklOB59W4IT7LZy6MEmFusuhSKacmsTcV1LAOW4uJ3K4#_=_
P3P: CP="Facebook does not have a P3P policy. Learn why here: http://fb.me/p3p"
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: locale=en_US; expires=Fri, 28-Oct-2011 00:09:38 GMT; path=/; domain=.facebook.com
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-FB-Server: 10.43.103.61
X-Cnection: close
Date: Fri, 21 Oct 2011 00:09:38 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

As you can see we can find the `#_=_` characters at the end of the **Location** value.

It's like the Redirect was taking into account the `#_=_` characters by adding them automatically to the loggedUrl.

Even when I try with `return Redirect("/");`, the `#_=_` is added from (almost) nowhere to my redirected url...

Any idea would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Regards,

LB

Comment: This caused issues with jQuery Mobile's URL hash listening. `$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;` solved it.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook has modified their authentication mechanism recently by adding this #*=* characters to the end of their response. The # symbol at the end of the string is actually creating the problem. So you can either truncate the query and do the redirect which will work fine.

Comment: What do you mean be truncate the query?

Comment: @capdragon: Fetch the url, remove the #= at the end and reissue the url requrest using any method (ajax, redirect etc..)