# why does return Redirect("/"); in ASP.NET MVC redirect to http://example.com/#_=_ Why is the named anchor added?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firefox, google-chrome, redirect, anchor

So here is the code:

```
private ActionResult MyMethod()
{
    //do stuff
    return Redirect("/");
}
```

I have a bunch of different methods like this in my app.  All behave well and redirect to the home page. But there is this one that redirects to `http://mysite.com/#_=_` in FF and Chrome while it redirects to `http://mysite.com/` in IE. And I don't want the named anchor added.  Can you tell me what's going on and what I can do to fix this.

Comment: I know nothing of ASP.NET, but this is interesting. I'm curious.

Comment: I don't know the answer of why this is happening, but are you able to use a RedirectToAction() instead of Redirect()? I've never had an issue with RedirectToAction() and I don't think I've ever had a reason to use Redirect() instead.

Comment: @hawkke If I use RedirectToAction it will change my url in the browser to http://mysite.com/home/index.html while I want the url in the browser to stay http://mysite.com/

Comment: @user277498 - It will only do that if you have your routing messed up.  It should redirect to the root of the app if home/index is your default route.

Comment: @MystereMan if I had my routing messed up, wouldn't all my return Redirect("/");
get messed up?  As it happens, only one method behaves badly.  All others behave fine.

Comment: @user277498 - No, Redirect does not use MVC routing.  It just redirects you to a specific URL.  I don't know why you are seeing the problem you're seeing, but it must be something in your code, because Redirect cannot do that.  My comment about your routing being messed up was in response to your comment to hawkke.

Answer (score 0):

This should not happen. If it happens there is probably some plugin installed on your browser that does this. Try disabling all plugins and/or javascript.

Comment: Thanks! I agree but it does. I turned off JavaSript in both Chrome and FF and the problem remained. I also tried it from a different computer and it still showed on that computer. On that computer there are no Chrome extensions and all FF plugins and extensions are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Facebook OAuth? I have the same thing happening but it is a result of using Facebook OAuth.

See: [Facebook Authentication and strange redirect behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844006/facebook-authentication-and-strange-redirect-behaviour)