# Clearing URL hash

Tags: javascript, html, url-routing, window.location

Visit `stackoverflow.com/#_=_` and `window.location.hash` evaluates to `#_=_`. Fine.

Now execute `window.location.hash = ''` to clear the hash, and the URL becomes `stackoverflow.com/#`. (Notice the trailing `#`.)

Why is the `#` in `window.location.hash` inconsistently included or excluded? How can the `#` be removed from the URL without reloading the page?

([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location) says

> [the hash is] the part of the URL that follows the # symbol, including the # symbol.

but that is not true for in the case of an empty hash.)

Comment: With which browser did you observe this behavior?

Comment: visiting `stackoverflow.com/#` also results in `window.location.hash === ''` so it's consistent behavior.

Comment: You are saying that manipulating `hash` with JavaScript leads to `#` in URL and empty `hash` property. Now visiting page with only `#` in URL also leads to empty `hash` property. `hash` property is filled only when there are other characters after `#` in URL and it is consistent behavior in all browsers.

Comment: I seem to recall that IE does not include the '#' as part of the location.hash -- just to point out some other inconsistency...

Comment: ie seems to add 'file///' at the beginning  when adding a # at the end of a url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the hash from window.location (URL) with JavaScript without page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397329/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-window-location-url-with-javascript-without-page-r)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

To answer the second question (removing the `#` without a page refresh):

```
history.pushState('', document.title, window.location.pathname);
```

Comment: Note: pushState is IE10 and above.

Comment: I prefer `replaceState` to achieve this.

Comment: Is there any solution for IE9? I tried `window.location.href.replace( /#.*/, "");` but it reloads the page.

Answer (score 4):

Answering to your first question:

According to the [window.location doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location) in Mozilla.org: *"the part of the URL that follows the # symbol, if there is one, including the # symbol.  **Empty string if the url does not contain # or has nothing after the #.**"*

Curiously, that document was just updated on 4/8/2013. Not sure if that was added after you checked the documentation.

By the way (and in reference to the answers), the window.location.hash and pushState are different concepts although close related.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things driving this behaviour:

- "Setting the hash property navigates to the named anchor without reloading the document." ([here](http://ific.uv.es/informatica/manuales/ClientReferenceJS13/location.html#1193379))
- "When you set the location object or any of its properties except hash[...]In JavaScript 1.1 and later, the effect of setting location depends on the user's setting for comparing a document to the original over the network." ([here](http://ific.uv.es/informatica/manuales/ClientReferenceJS13/location.html#1193176))

So basically, setting the hash property should never lead to a reload, setting any other property should lead to a reload (or perhaps an E-Tag/modified-since header check, depending on browser settings).

I would assume that for the sake of consistency, browser builders transform setting an empty hash, to setting '#' as hash. This way the url in the location bar does not lead to a reload. But this latter part is pure speculation.