# How to hide # in nginx

Tags: html, nginx

I have designed a page in html. I have created multiple links ( nav ) in and pointed it with same page section using id. for example, Next and this will display next section. While clicking the link, it updates the URL like ( localhost/myproject/index.html/#next ). But, I need to hide the '#' in that URL. ( localhost/myproject/index.html/next ). We are using nginx configuration. How can be it possible? Thanks in advance...

Comment: if you use angular try this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash)

Comment: no, i am using plain html

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397329/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-window-location-with-javascript-without-page-refresh and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322917/clearing-url-hash . Else Quentin answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible.

Fragment identifiers in URLs are handled entirely client side. They are never sent to the server, so the server can't access them.