# jQuery Slidetoggle issues

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I have a number of filters in the side menu of my page, which allow a user to filter the results that are displayed on the page.  I'm using jQuery slidetoggle to toggle the display of the filter items.

The html is as follows:

```
<div id="refinement-container">
<a href="#" class="closed">PRODUCT</a>
<ul id="product" class="items">      
    <li>items...</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and the jQuery I have so far is:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".items").hide();
  //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
  jQuery(".closed").click(function()
  {
    jQuery(this).next("ul.items").slideToggle(500);
    jQuery(this).next("ul.items").addclass('opened');
    jQuery(this).next("ul.items").removeclass('closed');

  });

 jQuery(".opened").click(function()
  {
    jQuery(this).next("ul.items").slideToggle(500);
    jQuery(this).next("ul.items").addclass('closed');
    jQuery(this).next("ul.items").removeclass('opened');

  });
});
```

The toggling works fine.  But the class is not changing on toggle, I'd like this to change so that I can change the background image of the link from + to - or vice versa.  I also tried toggleclass.
Also I want to be able to add another html element between the ul that is being toggled and the link that I click on to toggle it as follows:

```
<div id="refinement-container">
<a href="#" class="closed">PRODUCT</a><a href="" class="clear">clear</a>
<ul id="product" class="items">      
    <li>items...</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

But whenever I add an element in between, the toggle function stop working.  Is there a way around this?

Can anyone help me out with this please?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the code you're trying to use to add the 'clear' link?

Comment: I haven't written it yet, as I'm just concentrating on getting this working, but basically I will use the remove_query_arg worpress function to clear the product parameter from the current link.  Hence the reason I was using jQuery rather than $ as $ won't work within Wordpress unless I apply the function you suggested below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two mistakes that you're making here.

-You want to change the class of the clicked link, and not the class of the list that is being slide toggled.

-Theres no `class()` function. You could change the class attribute using the `attr()` function.. but it's cleaner to use `addClass()` and `removeClass()`.

So, instead of:

```
jQuery(this).next("ul.items").class('opened');
...
jQuery(this).next("ul.items").class('closed');
```

use this:

```
jQuery(this).removeClass('closed').addClass('opened');
...
jQuery(this).removeClass('opened').addClass('closed');
```

Comment: Hi, thanks.  I only want the class changed on the next ul element with class 'items' which is after the click link.  I have several of each on the page, and I want the user to be able to open and close each filter type as they please

Comment: If you want the ul to change it's class to "closed" or "opened" - why did you put a "closed" class on the PRODUCT link in the HTML code? And do you want the list of items to close when the user clicks the PRODUCT link a second time? Or do you want it to close when the user clicks the list itself?

Comment: Hi I have the closed class on the product link, so that I can display the open image as a background imaged on the link.  The image should change dependant on the current class.  I want the list of items to close when they click on the product link. The list items are where the user filters on each product attribute

Comment: What a donut... I've changed it it's now

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".items").hide();
  //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
  jQuery(".closed").click(function()
  {
    jQuery(this).next("ul.items").slideToggle(500);
    jQuery(this).removeclass('closed').addclass('opened');

  });
  
 jQuery(".opened").click(function()
  {
    jQuery(this).next("ul.items").slideToggle(500);
    jQuery(this).removeclass('opened').addclass('closed');

  });
});

Comment: Sorry I can't seem to format the code.  The class is still not changing :(

Comment: Right got it working, class should have had a capital letter rather than a small one. The issue I have now, is that although the class changes to opened, it won't change back to closed :(

Comment: Do update your code by editing your question and adding it in there so I can take a look at it - you'll be able to format it there

Answer (score 0):

There is no .class method in jQuery.

For adding class to element you should use `addClass` method.
For remove class you should use `removeClass` method.

Comment: I've changed it as per your recommendations, thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you add the `<a>`, you mess up your selector `next("ul.items")`

you could simple change the line to:

```
jQuery('.reset').next("ul.items").slideToggle(500);
```

Oh, now I see something else (probably the cause):

```
<ul items">
```

doesn't make any sense, either:

```
<ul class="items">
```

or

```
<ul id="items">
```

works for me, here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/REjdP/

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo... The code is built in php and I just striped all the php out of it.  the actual code I am using is correct. I am using the class items

Comment: I used your code and it works thanks, but the toggleClass behaviour is not working correctly on open and close

Comment: works for me, here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/REjdP/

Comment: Hi,  if you add additional refinement containers, clicking on the product link opens or closes all ul elements with the items class as opposed to just opening the next one after the clear link.  I have multiple attribute groups.

Comment: show me in the fiddle, then i can help you, and/or read this: http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/

Comment: Hi, have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/mDHnc/7/

Comment: you were hiding the UL's instead of the li's. try this: http://jsfiddle.net/mDHnc/9/. And please accept the answer afterwards...

Comment: Yes boss :) ... I would but nothing is happens when I click on any of the links.  I thought if I hide the ul, it would hide all the li's contained in that li automatically.  It worked before I added the reset code

Comment: Really appreciate your help by the way :)

Comment: you are welcome, it works for me, can anyone else confirm?

Comment: It works in Firefox but not in IE

Comment: it's not working in IE, because of the `console.log(ul);`. take that out and it will work. (or open developer tools - F12)

Comment: You were right, it works now, thank you very much.  One thing though, when I click on the link to open it, it bounces up to the beginning of the page, is there anything I can do to make the browser window remain at the particular filter that's been opened?

Comment: here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295845/remove-hash-without-page-jump, try google, its really helpful.

Comment: Thank you, I was searching for an answer in Google in the meantime.  I'm not all together lazy :).  You're a Star x